# Change your mind as you will, you will gain no…

Tags: inversion

I saw sentences like "Try as he might, he couldn't get the door open." I'd like to know whether the same pattern can be applied to the following sentence.

> Change your mind as you will, you will gain no additional support.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I think you can apply the pattern like that but there is one thing critical you do need to keep in mind.

For instance, it should be written like this:

> Change your mind as you wish, you would gain no additional support

totally, just 2 different words: wish and would.

Because you're not sure about if you would gain not additional support, you can use the certain word "will". Since the reason you can use only wish and would (could, might) in that case like the first sentence "Try as he might, he couldn't get the door open".

Comment: I don't usually think there's much point in commenting on old answers, but this one is so wrong that I am doing so. _Wish_ is a substantive verb, not an auxiliary, and cannot be used in this (rather literary) construction. The OP's suggested sentence, though a bit stilted, is fine, but web-sudo's emendation is not. -1